# Code to execute if a navigation fails

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hello I have no idea where I should start looking. I add few prop (before that my code run fine), then I get

> System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

so then I comment that changes, but that didn't help.

Could you suggest me where I should start looking for solution?

MyCode:

```
namespace SkydriveContent
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private LiveConnectClient client;
        FilesManager fileManager = new FilesManager();
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void signInButton1_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {


                client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
                infoTextBlock.Text = "Signed in.";
                client.GetCompleted +=
                    new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(OnGetCompleted);
                client.GetAsync("/me/skydrive/files/");
                fileManager.CurrentFolderId = "/me/skydrive/files/"; 
            }
            else
            {
                infoTextBlock.Text = "Not signed in.";
                client = null;
            }
        }

        void OnGetCompleted(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Gdy uda nam się podłaczyc do konta skydrive
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                signInButton1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;



                    infoTextBlock.Text = "Hello, signed-in user!";


                List<object> data = (List<object>)e.Result["data"];


                fileManager.FilesNames.Clear();
                filemanager.filesnames.add("..");
                foreach (IDictionary<string,object> item in data)
                {

                    File file = new File();              

                    file.fName = item["name"].ToString();
                    file.Type = item["type"].ToString();
                    file.Url = item["link"].ToString();
                    file.ParentId = item["parent_id"].ToString();
                    file.Id = item["id"].ToString();  

                    fileManager.Files.Add(file);
                    fileManager.FilesNames.Add(file.fName);

                }

                FileList.ItemsSource = fileManager.FilesNames;               
            }
            else
            {
                infoTextBlock.Text = "Error calling API: " +
                    e.Error.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void FileList_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (File item  in fileManager.Files)
            {
                if (item.fName == FileList.SelectedItem.ToString() )
                {
                    switch (item.Type)
                    { 
                        case "file":
                            MessageBox.Show("Still in progress");

                            break;
                        case "folder":

                            fileManager.CurrentFolderId = item.ParentId.ToString(); 
                            client.GetAsync(item.Id.ToString() + "/files");

                            break;
                        default:
                            MessageBox.Show("Coś nie działa");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (FileList.SelectedItem.ToString() == "..")
                {
                    client.GetAsync(fileManager.CurrentFolderId + "/files");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running stop at that line.

```
// Code to execute if a navigation fails
        private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check all of the URLs you have both in the XAML and code. When you get to the NavigationFailed function, it means that the phone tried to navigate to some page that did not existed. We would be able to help more if you could tell what were you doing when the app threw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

usually happens because of an **Uncaught Exception.** 
Either post the **code** which started giving problems, or the **stack trace** when you encounter this problem.
No one can tell anything without actually seeing what you are doing.

Comment: When does the exception happens and on which part of code. Try to update your question with the stack trace.

Comment: Amresh now I update with actual code, where application stop.

Comment: As answered by @gjulianm, your navigation is failing because of a non-existing page or incorrect URI for the page. Try checking the URI of the pages wherever you are navigating away from the current page.